# Request na url com laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-rotas

Estou tentando iniciar no `Laravel`, e estou tendo problemas com oa `requests`, quando faço apenas um `request` como por exemplo `localhost:8000/hoteis` tudo funciona ele busca a página e funciona perfeitamente, porém se faço `localhost:8000/hoteis/nomedohotel` ele não esta funcionando, no arquivo de rotas esta da seguinte maneira:

```
Route::get('/hoteis', 'HotelCrontroller@listarHoteis');
Route::get('/hoteis/{nome}', 'HotelCrontroller@mostraHotel');
```

Meu controller esta programado assim:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Request;

class HotelCrontroller extends Controller
{
    public function listarHoteis()
    {
        //DB::select('Aqui vem a query');
        $hoteis =  'Aqui vem os hoteis.';
        return view('hotel')->with('hoteis', $hoteis);
    }

    public function mostraHotel(){
       $nomeHotel = Request::route('name');
       return view('detalhehotel')->with('hotel', $nomeHotel);
    }
}
```

e na minha página esta da seguinte maneira:

```
@extends('index')
@section('conteudo')
<?php
    $hoteis = $hotel;
    
    echo $hoteis;
?>
@stop
```

Qual será o problema ? Para fazer o teste eu tentei entrar direto na pagina e funcionou perfeitamente.

> Descobri que pode haver alguma coisa com css ou algo do tipo, pois todas as paginas que eu escreve `/algo` ele apresenta a página de erro 404 estilizada porém quando coloco `/algo/algo` ele aparece a mesma página porém sem ser estilizada.
>
> Visualizei que os arquivos que ele está pegando vem assim `http://localhost:8000/aa/css/app_2.min.css` por este motivo todo o estilo está vindo de forma errada, como fazer para ele carregar apenas assim `http://localhost:8000/css/app_2.min.css`. Assim irá funcionar o que eu quero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso, você deve estar inserindo os assets de maneira errada. Ao se referir ao caminho de um asset, você deve usar a facade `asset` no seu template assim: {{ asset('css/app_2.min.css') }}. Você provavelmente está usando a url atual, por isso está adicionando a rota atual no caminho do CSS.

Comment: Isto não resolve meu problema, o problema esta na rota, pois quando coloco sub n rota da erro. Exemplo /hotéis e /hotéis/nome do hotel no segundo da problem e não careca o site, vi que o caminho dos CSS, JAVASCRIPT, ESTA COM PROBLEMAS.

Comment: Nesse caso, você deve estar inserindo os assets de maneira errada. Ao se referir ao caminho de um asset, você deve usar a facade `asset` no seu template assim: `{{ asset('css/app_2.min.css') }}`. Você provavelmente está usando a url atual, por isso está fazendo essa adição da sua rota. Se isso ajudar, avise que eu mudo a resposta.

Comment: ajudou sim, obrigado

Comment: Como fica o caminho todo ? O link coloco no local de que ?

Comment: A função `asset` vai escrever o caminho baseado nas configurações da sua aplicação. Se você estiver com a configuração padrão do Laravel, basta escrever a função como comentei anteriormente. O caminho final fica como você mencionou na pergunta: `http://localhost:8000/css/app_2.min.css`. Você deve usar essa função no seu template do Blade q contém a parte dos estilos.

Comment: Deu tudo certinho

Comment: Ok. Acabei de editar a resposta. Marque-a como correta para fecharmos esse tópico. Obrigado.

Answer (score 1):

> porém se faço localhost:8000/hoteis/nomedohotel ele não esta funcionando

Pode arranjar informação do erro que aparece? Entretanto, verifique se tem o .htaccess configurado.

Na root do projecto:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Na pasta /public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```